# How to clear/empty BlockingCollection in c#

Tags: c#, collections, blockingcollection

I have a thread which is adding items to a BlockingCollection. I want to clear the BlockingCollection. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to read all the items from the BlockingCollection and assign to [Discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards)

```
while (collection.TryTake(out _)){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use the overload of `GetConsumingEnumerable` that takes a `CancellationToken;` then, if anything goes wrong from the producing side, it can cancel the consumer.

And you can use it

```
 public static void Clear<T>(this BlockingCollection<T> blockingCollection)
{
    if (blockingCollection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("blockingCollection");
    }

    while (blockingCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        T item;
        blockingCollection.TryTake(out item);
    }
}
```

And you can even use this site

[Use ForEach to Remove Items in a BlockingCollection](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-use-foreach-to-remove)